# Is an Eigen matrix created automatically on the heap?

Tags: c++, matrix, memory, eigen

This question might be stupid, but I am am a beginner.
When I create an  Eigen::MatrixXd in a local scope like this:

```
    void foo(){
        Eigen::MatrixXd m(rows,cols);
        // do stuff
    }
```

Will the object be on the heap or the stack?
I would expect it to be on the stack, since I don't use the 'new' keyword.

Comment: I think you would benefit from reading [this](https://eigen.tuxfamily.org/dox/TopicInsideEigenExample.html)

Comment: It's not your problem. That is for Eigen to manage. Why do you care?

Comment: @nwp: I just try to understand what I am doing.  Imagine I call foo() from a loop thousands of times. If I declare 'm' just as above it will be more expensive when its on the heap, right?

Comment: So what you care about is not if it's on the stack or heap, but how it performs. Profilers and benchmarks answer that question. But performance is very tricky. Constructing on the heap and skipping a dynamic memory allocation is faster for construction, but when you move the object away it makes a deep copy whereas the heap version may only copy a pointer.

Comment: @nwp: Did you mean "Constructing on the stack"?

Comment: I did. Sorry. Can't edit anymore.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`m` has *automatic storage duration* like any other type declared in this way.

Of course `Eigen::MatrixXd` will manage much of its internal memory dynamically, but you do not need to concern yourself with that.

Comment: You might be well aware of the differences between `Eigen::MatrixXd` and e.g. `Eigen::Matrix4d` (as this answer only mentions the former), but just in case: note that Eigen explicitly does not make use of dynamic memory for its fixed-sized specializations of `Eigen::Matrix`, meaning that if `m` where to have been a `Eigen::Matrix4d`, its internal data storage would have been placed on the stack.

Comment: Heap allocations can easily become the most costly part of a poorly-written library.  Most  good programmers should be concerned with utilizing their hardware efficiently -- that includes being concerned with how memory is allocated.

Answer (score 10):

### Instances of specializations of `Eigen::Matrix` can be stored either on the heap or the stack

As is mentioned in [the accepted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55966077/4573247), `m` has automatic storage duration. It is important to point out, however, that the subsequent statement that

> Of course `Eigen::MatrixXd` will manage much of its internal memory dynamically, but you do not need to concern yourself with that.

does not apply, in general, for instances of specializations of `Eigen::Matrix`, and important to also point out that this is indeed something you might want to concern yourself with, particularly if are working in a context where dynamic memory is disallowed (say, an embedded environment).

#### Dynamic-sized `Eigen` matrices

You are using a dynamically-sized matrix (emphasis on the **`X`** in [`Eigen::MatrixXd`](https://eigen.tuxfamily.org/dox/group__matrixtypedefs.html#ga99b41a69f0bf64eadb63a97f357ab412). Any `Eigen::MatrixX...` type is just a typedef for `Eigen::Matrix< ..., Dynamic , Dynamic >`, where [`Dynamic`](https://eigen.tuxfamily.org/dox/namespaceEigen.html#ad81fa7195215a0ce30017dfac309f0b2) signifies that its size is not known at compile-time:

> `const int Eigen::Dynamic`
>
> This value means that a positive quantity (e.g., a size) is not known at compile-time, and that instead the value is stored in some runtime variable.

The Eigen documenation for [`Eigen::Matrix`](https://eigen.tuxfamily.org/dox/classEigen_1_1Matrix.html), that all `Eigen::MatrixX...` are specializations of, makes it clear that the data of dynamic-sized matrices will be stored on the heap [**emphasis** mine]:

> **Fixed-size versus dynamic-size:**
>
> Fixed-size means that the numbers of rows and columns are known are
> compile-time. In this case, Eigen **allocates the array of
> coefficients as a fixed-size array**, as a class member. ...
>
> Dynamic-size means that the numbers of rows or columns are not
> necessarily known at compile-time. In this case they are runtime
> variables, and the array of coefficients **is allocated dynamically on
> the heap**.

#### Fixed-sized `Eigen` matrices

From the first paragraph quoted above it is clear, however, that if `m` were to have been a fixed-size `Eigen::Matrix` specialization, its data would be (as it has automatic storage duration) stored on the stack. This is important guarantee e.g. for projects where dynamic memory allocation is not allowed (e.g. embedded).

Indeed, Eigen even offers an internal preprocessor directive, `EIGEN_RUNTIME_NO_MALLOC`, that can be used to ban any dynamic memory allocation within the Eigen module.

> These macros are mainly meant for people developing Eigen and for
> testing purposes. Even though, they might be useful for power users
> and the curious for debugging and testing purpose, they **should not
> be used** by real-word code.
>
> `EIGEN_RUNTIME_NO_MALLOC` - if defined, a new switch is introduced
> which can be turned on and off by calling
> `set_is_malloc_allowed(bool)`. If `malloc` is not allowed and Eigen
> tries to allocate memory dynamically anyway, an assertion failure
> results. Not defined by default.

Emphasis, however, on *"**should not be used** by real-word code"*, but it could be used by users of Eigen for testing purposes.

**Fixed-size matrices may still end up on the heap!**

As mentioned by @superjax in a comment:

> One last thing I would add is that fixed-size matrices exceeding the [EIGEN_STACK_ALLOCATION_LIMIT](https://eigen.tuxfamily.org/dox/TopicPreprocessorDirectives.html) will also be allocated on the heap. (The default is 128kb, but that can be changed)

Comment: One last thing I would add is that fixed-size matrices exceeding the [`EIGEN_STACK_ALLOCATION_LIMIT`](https://eigen.tuxfamily.org/dox/TopicPreprocessorDirectives.html) will also be allocated on the heap. (The default is 128kb, but that can be changed)

Comment: @superjax Thanks, I've added your comment to the answer.

Answer (score 0):

**Fixed size objects in Eigen library**

All the fixed size objects e.g. Matrix2f, Vector3f etc. are allocated using array declared onto stack. If you check out *Eigen/src/Core/DenseStorage.h*,

```
struct plain_array
{
  T array[Size];
  ...
```

**Dynamic size objects in Eigen library**

The dynamic size objects (and intermediate objects created during run-time) get their memory using malloc()/realloc(). You can check it in *Eigen/src/Core/util/Memory.h*